# PHP e-mail displaying special chars as �

Tags: php, email

I have searched back and forth through here and Google. But no luck.

Trying to send e-mails with PHP I have the following:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$Empfaenger = "mail@someone.com";  
$Mailbetreff = "Subject";  
$Header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";  
$Header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";  
$Header .= "From: ";  
$Header .= $Sender;  
$Header .= "\n";  
$Header .= "Straße: Blabla";  
mail($Empfaenger, $Mailbetreff, "", $Header);
```

Characters like "ß" and "ä" and the like always arrive as �.
As the contents of the e-mail will be generated from a form and I do not know, which chars will be uses it won't help to replace the one "ß" with &szlig", obviously.

I have also tried iso-8859-1 and encoding strings with htmlentities(), but that only switches the outcome from � to Ã for all special chars.

In case, that is relevant: The server runs PHP 5.2.7

Comment: add quetos around your email address please.

Comment: The page where the form is sended from, what encoding is using?

Comment: The html uses `<meta charset="utf-8" />`.

Comment: Change to `<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />` there and in the header of the mail.

Comment: @ojovirtual This should not matter... That request has been handled and dealt with... The thing that matters is that the content of the used variables is in the correct character encoding ($Empfanger, $Mailbetreff, the mail contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This row should not in the `$Header`:

```
$Header .= "Straße: Blabla";
```

You need to create `$body` variable for body, and add that as the 3rd parameter of the mail.

So you need to use your code like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$Empfaenger = "a@b.c";
$Mailbetreff = "Subject";
$Header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$Header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$Header .= "From: ";
$Header .= $Sender;
$Header .= "\r\n";

$Body = "Straße: Blabla";
mail($Empfaenger, $Mailbetreff, $Body, $Header);
```

**NOTE:**
Your php file encoding should be UTF-8 also!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Stupid mistake. Thanks for tipping me off.

Comment: @NilsMielke Please look at RichardBernards' answer. Headers should end with `\r\n`, not simply `\n`. Malformed emails are more likely to be blocked by spam filters, if they even arrive.

Comment: @NilsMielke The line `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` has nothing to do with the email being sent and can be removed

Answer (score 2):

First of all, header-ends should be terminated by a CRLF (\r\n)
Second of all... You are adding the contents of the message in the header, not in the content of the mail...

Check the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function for the parameters

Comment: +1 for pointing out the CRLF thing, as well as the header/body thing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks... seems like the pre-chewed comment gets the answer-cred though :p

Comment: Thanks for this, @RichardBernards. The other answer was clearer for a low-level developer like myself. Hence the acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use html entities [Html Entities list](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

The correct use of ß would be: `&szlig;`

Comment: @ojovirtual ehh didn't notice that sorry.